# Google Youtube API V3 Just Get Data

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There are changes made on the Youtube API, i see bunch of stuff.
But all i want is to get the Youtube title and img thumbnail. DO i really need to go all the stuff regestering for api, etc just to get the title and img of a single video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out.

Yes, you really need to register an to the API Developers Console.

if you are like me and just want to get the title or thumbnail use the
**Public API access**

but if you are looking more for the extreme controls on your video out of youtube. You can do that but you have to use the
**OAuth Credentials**

to get simple data i used [**>>THIS<<**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) basically the **snippet** holds the information for the Video like *title*,*uploaded by*,*uploaded on* etc. .